# Typescript: Passing in an inherited class name as an argument to a function

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, constructor

I have the following code (simplified):

```
class Component {

}

class CameraComponent extends Component {
    foo: number;

    constructor(bar: number) {
        super()
    }
}

function doSomething(klass: typeof Component) {

}

doSomething(CameraComponent);
```

This gives me the following error:

`TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof CameraComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Component'.`

If I modify `CameraComponent` to this it works fine:

```
class CameraComponent extends Component {
    foo: number;

    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Why can't to change the constructor signature? Is there some way I can make this work without resorting to `any`?

Comment: have you considered using generics?

Comment: @DanielA.White generics don't figure into it really, yes you could also use generics if needed but that is a different issue ..

Comment: true but there could be an x-y issue here. @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: @DanielA.White maybe, there are use cases for the non generic version. If `doSomething` does not return a value based on the type of the passed in constructor (and in the OP it does not) then generics are not needed, you gain nothing from them. If on the other hand `doSomething` returns an instance of the component or needs to take the arguments for the constructor then yes, generics would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoded in `typeof Component` is not only the fact that `klass` is a constructor that must return a `Component` but also the parameters of that constructor. So if you pass in a `CameraComponent` requiring a different number of parameters you will get an error

If you want to accept any constructor that returns a `Component` you can use `new (...a: any[]) => Component`

```
class Component {

}

class CameraComponent extends Component {
    foo: number;

    constructor(bar: number) {
        super()
    }
}

function doSomething(klass: new (...a: any[]) => Component) {

}

doSomething(CameraComponent);
```